# Customizing pagation in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to set something where pagation won't show up on the first page, but instead, say "Start Gallery". Then the 2nd,3rd, etc pages will be as normal. How can I acomplish this?

Comment: Creating a child theme and editing it directly would probably be the best way!

Comment: I'm curious as to what "normal" means here. There's different pagination styles where on some sites, there's only the "next" and "last" page option, where as on other sites, theres page numbers users can choose from along with "next" and "last", etc. And also, setting this up can be done in so many ways even without wordpress, and there are probably plugins for wordpress that allow you to customize pagination options.